# Count query giving different result with same time range in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am doing aggregation of records in a collection with time interval of five minute using match as follows

```
{ "$match" : { "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1460953500000 , "$lte" : 1460953800000})
```

scrip run at time interval like

```
10:01, (interval will be 9:55 to 10:00)
10:06, (interval will be 10:00 to 10:05)
```

after running above match query i am getting different count.
Count of document changes till 1-2 minute after time passed
For example i run query of count in collection

Query hit time

```
10:01:05
    db.xxx.count({ "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1460953500000 , "$lte" : 1460953800000})

Count : 44350

10:01:015
db.xxx.count({ "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1460953500000 , "$lte" : 1460953800000})

Count : 44578

10:01:40
db.xxx.count({ "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1460953500000 , "$lte" : 1460953800000})

Count : 44830
```

and this time onward count become stable.

I have found this
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#journal-process
Journaling Process

> With journaling, MongoDB’s storage layer has two internal views of the data set: the private view, used to write to the journal files, and the shared view, used to write to the data files:
>
> 1. MongoDB first applies write operations to the private view.
> 2. MongoDB then applies the changes in the private view to the on-disk journal files in the journal directory roughly every 100 milliseconds. MongoDB records the write operations to the on-disk journal files in batches called group commits. Grouping the commits help minimize the performance impact of journaling since these commits must block all writers during the commit. Writes to the journal are atomic, ensuring the consistency of the on-disk journal files. For information on the frequency of the commit interval, see storage.journal.commitIntervalMs.
> 3. Upon a journal commit, MongoDB applies the changes from the journal to the shared view.
> 4. Finally, MongoDB applies the changes in the shared view to the data files. More precisely, at default intervals of 60 seconds, MongoDB asks the operating system to flush the shared view to the data files. The operating system may choose to flush the shared view to disk at a higher frequency than 60 seconds, particularly if the system is low on free memory. To change the interval for writing to the data files, use the storage.syncPeriodSecs setting.

Is this the reason for count diff ?. I am using mongodb 3.2
Please help me to find stable count result.

Comment: I am having same issue. My query is `count all documents less than certain date`, and the data is 1 month old. But even then, my count query returns different results.

Answer (score 0):

You have found the answer yourself. To check how its working and records count waiting to be written to the disk using this command:

```
db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } )
```

Comment: Hi @Satish thank for ur reply.But if it actually happened behind the scene then how we achieve real time analysis using mongodb.